# MySQL Common Table Expression Error Message

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I wrote the below query with a CTE attempting to return all the dates on which daily transactions exceeded the average of all daily transactions; however, MySQL keeps returning an error message for something around line 1. I've attached a description of the transactions table as well as the query, any help would be greatly appreciated.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'total_daily_transactions as
> (select
> t.created_at,
> ' at line 1

query:

```
with total_daily_transactions as
        (select
            t.created_at,
            sum(t.amount) as daily_transactions
        from transactions t
        group by t.created_at) tdt,
    avg_daily_transactions as
        (select
             round(avg(daily_transactions),0) as avg_transactions
        from total_daily_transactions) adt
select *
from total_daily_transactions tdt
join avg_daily_transactions adt
on tdt.daily_transactions > adt.avg_transactions;
```

transactions table:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    created_at DATE NOT NULL,
    posted_at DATE NOT NULL,
    transactions VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    sub_category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        DEFAULT '',
    amount INT NOT NULL,
    alert VARCHAR(255)
        DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but posting images of technical information like code, sample data, or schema information, rather than formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen on this site other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored. If you want a good, prompt, answer, you will edit the original question to remove the image and use formatted text instead. Also, posting that you got an error, without posting the exact error message (again: as **formatted text**) is never well received.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is simply a meaningless repetition of information already available in the tags. The title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey meaning to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your title as written has no meaning at all. Also, please read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to give CTEs aliases at the end of their creation, `...group by t.created_at) tdt`, and `...from total_daily_transactions) adt`, this will lead to a syntax error.

Also, you may simplify your query as the following:

```
WITH avg_daily_transactions AS
(
  SELECT created_at, SUM(amount) daily_transactions
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY created_at
)
SELECT D.created_at, D.daily_transactions, D.avg_transactions
FROM
(
  SELECT created_at, daily_transactions, ROUND(AVG(daily_transactions) OVER (), 0) avg_transactions
  FROM avg_daily_transactions
) D
WHERE D.daily_transactions > D.avg_transactions
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EGUGueIl).

If you are using MySQL 5.x, you can't use CTEs neither window functions; they are not supported. If you used them in this version you will get a syntax error. In this case you may try the following query:

```
SET @AVRG =(
    SELECT ROUND(AVG(daily_transactions), 0) 
    FROM 
    (
     SELECT created_at, SUM(amount) daily_transactions
     FROM transactions
     GROUP BY created_at
    ) T  );

SELECT created_at, SUM(amount) daily_transactions, @AVRG avg_transactions
FROM transactions
GROUP BY created_at
HAVING SUM(amount) > @AVRG;
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gJTc_gNI) on MySQL 5.7

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for your help on this. I tried running the suggested queries in your demo but the error message persisted: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'avg_daily
_transactions AS
(
  SELECT created_at, SUM(amount) daily_transactions
' at line 1

Comment: What version of mysql you are using? 5.x versions doesn't support CTE

Comment: You may check the updated answer.

Comment: I was on 5.7, upgrading to version 8 did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH total_daily_transactions
AS (SELECT t.created_at,
           SUM(t.amount) AS daily_transactions
    FROM transactions t
    GROUP BY t.created_at),
     avg_daily_transactions
AS (SELECT ROUND(AVG(daily_transactions), 0) AS avg_transactions
    FROM total_daily_transactions)
SELECT *
FROM total_daily_transactions tdt
    JOIN avg_daily_transactions adt
        ON tdt.daily_transactions > adt.avg_transactions;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).